# Mixed Content issue with Heroku and Soundcloud API

Tags: node.js, heroku, https, soundcloud, mixed-content

I'm trying to deploy a test app to Heroku that involves downloading tracks from the Soundcloud API. The core functionality works fine locally, but runs into the mixed-content error when attempting to download tracks with an xmlhttprequest to the Soundcloud API due to Heroku's ssl layer.

I've searched the other mixed content questions and the general response is to add the 's' to the request or eliminate the http(s) altogether. My request url for the SC API is already https, but it looks like SC is using a redirect based on the error messages in the console. Am I just stuck?

The only workaround I can think of would be to request from the server and then pipe the response to the client... which would be fine for my app's functionality, but seems like a hack.  Any ideas?  Thanks!